# MQTT issue: using adafruitIO, some of my data is not being sent

Tags: python, mqtt

Don't really post, only read.  but im having a strange issue with my python code for publishing data i collect from bluetooth devices.

**Background**

I have adapted python code that runs on a raspberry pi from a collegue to publish data to an mqtt sever, in this case adafuitIO. the code only used to collect the data throughout the day, then email it off to a dedicated email account. however, this has become "old fashioned" for its purpose, so i have added a live publish to adafruitIO to track the data easier.

the bulk of the code gathers data from bluetooth devices that we program with a set device name so it only connects to those devices. and iterates through the devices collecting the 7 values from the sensors on the device. then writes each of the values to a file on the pi to be later emailed out.

my addition to this code, takes the mac address of the device, and all the values for the sensors and sends it to the broker as follows:

```
client.publish(user_name/groups/macaddress/json,j)
# used to create or publish to an existing group on the broke named the devices macaddress
# macaddress being the devices macaddress
# j being the below
    # sample json to send
    # {
    #     "feeds": {
    #         "ETH": 1,
    #         "Hum": 54,
    #         "temp-1": 18,
    #         "temp-2": 85
    #     }
    # }
```

**Problem**

The problem i am having is that 1 bluetooth device will not publish the data. its always the same device (macaddress) that doesnt send, whether it is found first, last or anywhere between. i originally had 4 devices, but have since set up another, thinking that maybe the broker wasnt allowing so many data points sent.  however, the newest mac address is publishing fine.  the code for the mqtt part is below:

```
def uploadMQTT(macs, mqttList):
    # Imports
    import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
    import ssl
    import random
    import sys
    import time
    import json

    mac = macs
    feedValues = mqttList
    username = "user_name"
    key ="password"
    feeds = ["temp-2-vs", "temp-2-vm", "temp-1-vs", "temp-1-vm", "hum-vs", "hum-vm", "eth-vm"]
    broker = "io.adafruit.com"
    port = 8883

    #create dictionary of the feed names
    feedDict = dict((feed,0) for feed in feeds)

    # Create create client object
    client = mqtt.Client()
    # set up client username and password
    client.username_pw_set(username, key)
    # Can encrypt the connection so added the below, may not be needed
    client.tls_set(certfile=None,
        keyfile=None,
        cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED)

    # called when is connected to broker
    def connected(client, userdata, message, tmp=None):
        print("connected")

    # called when is disconnected from broker
    def disconnected(client, userdata, message, tmp=None):
        print("disconnected")

    # called when a return message is sent from broker after publishing to a feed
    def message(client, userdata, message, tmp=None):
        print("Received message " + str(message.payload)
            + " on topic '" + message.topic
            + "' with QoS " + str(message.qos))

    # set up the use of the above callbacks
    client.on_connect = connected
    client.on_disconnect = disconnected
    client.on_message = message

    # used to connect to the broker
    client.connect(broker,port)

    client.loop_start()

    #counter for iterationg through feedValues
    count = 0
    #create string for publishing
    currfeed = (username + "/groups/" + mac)
    for y in feeds:
        # first test, assign a random number to each value in feedDict
        #value = random.randint(0,100)
        # assign the feedValue to value for the feedDict
        value = str(feedValues[count])
        #assign values to the dictionary including the mac address (adafruitio doesnt add the group name to the downloaded file name)
        feedDict[y] = value + "," + macs
        count += 1
    #create dictionary for turning to json
    jsonDict = {'feeds':feedDict}
    #create json
    j = json.dumps(jsonDict, indent = 4)
    # publish to user_name/groups/mac/json, j
    # used to create or publish to an existing group on the broke named the devices macaddress
    # macaddress being the devices macaddress
    # j being the below
    client.publish(currfeed + "/json",j)
```

I have used so many prints to see if anything is different for that specific mac address, but the feedValues is formatted the same, same with mac address, jsonDict and j.  I have also  tried removing a couple of devices (including the main culprit) to see if it stops sending any of the others, but all of them are still publishing to the broker.

really not sure why that 1 mac address is having issues being published. getting a bit frustrated with it!

Can anyone see an issue with the code? or maybe understand why i could be getting this issue?

on a side note, i have the premium adafruitIO for unlimited feeds/groups, and higher datapoint limit per minute. i should never reach the data point limit as it typically takes 45 seconds per devices to read the values and publish.  Even if it somehow managed to run through 8 devices in 60 seconds, that is still less than 60 datapoints

**Tried**

So far i have been running through the code, adding print lines to make sure all the json that is being sent is correct, making sure the group it is publishing the json to is correct and anything else i can think of to check that there are no errors with values or mac address and it adding unwanted characters.

below is what i get from printing j (the jsondump) the top one publishes, the bottom one does not

```
{
    "feeds": {
        "temp-1-vm": "22792,CB:B1:03:56:69:C1",
        "temp-2-vs": "40950,CB:B1:03:56:69:C1",
        "hum-vm": "4470,CB:B1:03:56:69:C1",
        "eth-vm": "409486,CB:B1:03:56:69:C1",
        "hum-vs": "40950,CB:B1:03:56:69:C1",
        "temp-2-vm": "831,CB:B1:03:56:69:C1",
        "temp-1-vs": "40950,CB:B1:03:56:69:C1"
    }
}
{
    "feeds": {
        "temp-1-vm": "16667,EB:10:08:5E:22:91",
        "temp-2-vs": "38336,EB:10:08:5E:22:91",
        "hum-vm": "17069,EB:10:08:5E:22:91",
        "eth-vm": "385375,EB:10:08:5E:22:91",
        "hum-vs": "38803,EB:10:08:5E:22:91",
        "temp-2-vm": "32165,EB:10:08:5E:22:91",
        "temp-1-vs": "37314,EB:10:08:5E:22:91"
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like this device is broken or misconfigured (or similar). can you verify that it is working ?

Comment: the device still sends the correct data and is added to the text file for emailing, it also creates the correct json data to send to the correct macaddress named group

Comment: so what exactly is the problem ?  where are you stuck ?

Comment: with the json shown at the bottom of the post, the first one publishes to the broker with "user_name/groups/mac/json, j" , the second doesnt.  i also have 3 other devices that, other than the value and mac address, are the same. regardless on whether it publishes the EB:..:91 mac address first, second, last it will not publish the values for that device. i tried just creating the group and feeds on the broker and seeing if it would send then, but still nothing.  really dont understand why 4+ other devices work, but this one doesnt

Comment: just pulled the mqtt function out to its own file and hard coded in the mac address as "mac" and using random numbers to fill feedValues and it published as expected.

I then added some other bogus mac address and the bogus ones published, but that specific mac address (EB:..:91) did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a couple of days of pulling my hair out trying to work this out. turns out it was an issue on the broker side. a couple of days after posting this i started to get readings from the one i was having issues with.  i played around with it a little to see if i could figure out what the issue was. not having much support to get in touch with, this is purely speculative.
i believe that, after deleting the "group" named after that mac address, there may be some kind of "cooldown" period of creating groups/feeds that share the name of recently deleted groups/feeds.